# How is React Context implemented?

Tags: reactjs

How is Context *implemented* by the React library?

Is Context copied to every single child component? Or is the context found by iterating through parent components? Or is it a combination with some form of caching? Or something else completely?

Comment: Does this link answer your questions ? - https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: No, sorry, I'm interested in how the library is implemented, not how to use it.